# How to enable text selection in jQuery Autocomplete?

Tags: autocomplete

I am using a jQuery autocomplete to allow for users to search through a directory. I have it setup so that the Drop Down doesn't disappear once they click away.

However, I need it so that they can copy, say the email address, from the dropdown. However, when I click and drag nothing happens and the text does not get highlighted.

I have tried:

```
$("ul.ui-autocomplete *").enableSelection();
```

And I have tried:

```
*{
     -ms-user-select: text;
     -moz-user-select: text;
     -khtml-user-select: text;
     -webkit-user-select: text;
     user-select: text;
 }
```

That's all I could think of. Any ideas?

**EDIT 4/14/13**

You can see live version of this issue by going to http://wnmu.edu and clicking on "Search" on the yellow bar on the right.

Comment: Would you be interested in putting a button next to the dropdown field that would say "copy" or something of that sort?

Comment: What about Html Code and making fiddle !!!

Comment: See updated post. Sorry, I didn't do this earlier.

Comment: @thegreyspot I see that wnmu.edu is working as you wanted — could you share exactly what you did? I'm trying to look through the code but I'm having trouble finding specifically how you achieved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a copy selected value-link or -button outside the dropdown list that copies the address to the clipboard?
That should be pretty straight forward using clippy (https://github.com/mojombo/clippy) or similar.

Comment: idk about that... i have things like email address, link,phone number and I would hate to have a button next each of those :/

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant with drop downs. I thought you meant you had drop down list, ie the html select tag.